# Local Storage with multiple key value pair

Tags: reactjs

Am creating a comment section using react for that i need to store all the input text into the local storage.
but the problem am facing is my local storage get reloaded when ever i write another comment on comment section.

how to add the unique key value into the local storate???

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest you to store `Comments` in an `array` and then store it in `localStorage`.

Do something like this -

```
const AddComments = () => {
    let commentsArray = localStorage.getItem("Comments") // Get Previous Comments
    let temp = []

    if(commentsArray !== null) {
        temp = [...JSON.parse(commentsArray)]
    }

    temp.push({
        comment: "New Comment",
        _id: "id of new comment",
    })
    localStorage.setItem("Comments", JSON.stringify(temp)) // This will add new comment to previous comment
}
```

Comment: You prob need `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have something like this:

```
const comments = [];
// some form to create a comment storing it in a var comment
comments.push(comment);
const commentsJsonified = JSON.stringify(comments);
localStorage.setItem('comments', commentsJsonified);
```

If so, then you can grab the comments from local storage using

`const comments = localStorage.getItem('comments')`

parse them with

`const parsedComments = JSON.parse(comments)`

then add to the parsedComments array and put it back into local storage. Whether or not you're using an array or a different data structure to hold comments, it should be the same. You could also consider using [Redux-Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) if you need access to posts, comments, etc. in multiple parts of the app.